# How to save data from a listbox and its corresponding value in a textbox into an xml

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, textbox, listbox

I have some items in a listbox, and when i click on the particular item, i need to enter the corresponding value in a text box, and these have to be saved in an xml. For example. my listbox contains name and age. I click on name, enter the corresponding value(say John) in the text box and i need to save this to an xml. This has to be done for all the items in the listbox. I am a beginner and not too sure how to go about it. I hope my question is comprehensbile. How can i go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
        {

           xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(TextBox1.Text);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {

            Debug.WriteLine("  " + ex.ToString());

        }


        if (null == xmlDoc)
        {
            // Load from Isolated Storage failed so load from default settings in XAP file
            xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("Default.xml", LoadOptions.None);
        }
        xmlDoc.Element("").Add(new XElement("username"));
        xmlDoc.Save(strmSettings);

        strmSettings.Close();
```

Comment: Hi,When i do this it says : The name 'strmSettings' does not exist in the current context.. How do i go about this?